# Why can't $pV$ work generate entropy in a reservoir?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, work, entropy

Consider a reservoir A' which enforces some temperature $T'$ and pressure $p'$ on some system A which is undergoing some process. Primed quantities will refer to system A'.

The entropy of A' should depend on its volume and energy since its number of accessible states, $\Omega'$, depends on these quantities: $\Omega'=\Omega'(E',V')$. Then when system A gives off heat $Q$ and expands by $\Delta V$, we should be able to expand and obtain (where $(E',V')$ are the relevant quantities of A' before the process)
$$ \Delta S' = k(\ln\Omega'(E'-Q,V'-\Delta V)-\ln\Omega'(E',V'))= k\left(\frac{\partial\ln\Omega'(E',V')}{\partial E'}(-Q)+\frac{\partial\ln\Omega'(E',V')}{\partial V'}(-\Delta V)\right) = k\left(\frac{1}{kT'}(-Q)+\frac{p'}{kT'}(-\Delta V)\right) = \frac{-Q}{T'}-\frac{p'\Delta V}{T'}$$ which is not the same as the standard expression $ \Delta S' = \frac{-Q}{T'}$. Where have I gone wrong? This question has arisen in the derivation in Chapter 8.3 of Reif of the condition that a system at fixed temperature and pressure seeks to minimize its Gibbs free energy.

Comment: You need to also include the change in energy due to work accompanying the expension

Comment: @user3725600 Ah, are you saying I should rewrite $-Q$ as $-Q+p' \Delta V$ and that will make the given term vanish? If so, and if you put that as an answer I can give you a check. That makes sense.

Comment: Are you saying the system A' is the reservoir A'?

Comment: @BobD That is correct.

Comment: I'm not conversant in statistical mechanics, so I'll take a pass on this one. But I will say I find your description confusing. It appears you have two systems, A and A'. You say A' enforces some pressure p' on system A, but you don't say how. You say system A gives off heat Q but you don't say to where (is it to A'? somewhere else?) You say A undergoes some process, but you don't say what process. And so forth.

Comment: @BobD This is a standard construction in statistical mechanics. The theory isn’t concerned with how the process occurs, it can just be shown that this equilibrium comes about.

Comment: Ok. Like I said I’m not conversant in statistical mechanics

Comment: Even so, to be clear, only an irreversible pV process can generate entropy

Comment: Since A gives off heat Q, then I can assume Q is negative, correct?

Comment: @BobD That is true.

Comment: If $\Delta V$ is the change in volume of system A, why are you including it in your equation for the change in entropy of system A'?

Comment: @BobD Because the volume of A' (the rest of the universe) changes by minus that amount.

Comment: One last question and I may then offer an answer. When you say "Consider a reservoir A' which enforces some temperature $T'$ and pressure $p'$ on some system A" do you mean system A and A' are always in thermal and mechanical equilibrium, i.e., that the temperature of A is kept at $T'$, and the pressure of A is kept at $p'$?

Comment: When I said kept at, I meant infinitesimally close to

Answer (score 0):

> Why can't $pV$ work generate entropy in a reservoir?

The short answer is it can, if the $pV$ work is irreversible. Reversible work neither generates nor transfers entropy.

So what it boils down to is this, is the $pV$ work done in your scenario reversible or not. Based on your description of the scenario it appears the work is reversible, as discussed below.

Based on our discussions in comments, my understanding of the scenario is as follows:

1. The systems $A$ and $A'$ together constitute the universe.
2. You stated reservoir A' "enforces" some temperature ′ and pressure ′ on some system A". I interpret this to mean that system A and A' are always in thermal and mechanical equilibrium, i.e., that the temperature of A is infinitesimally greater than ′ (for reversible heat transfer from $A$ to $A'$), and the pressure of A is infinitesimally greater than ′(for reversible compression work done by A on A').
3. By some (unspecified) process, system $A$ undergoes $p'dV$ work resulting in expansion $\Delta V$ of $A$ while at the same time giving off heat $Q$ (Exactly how A can expand and at the same time give off heat is not clear to me, but we will assume so).
4. Given (1), $A'$ absorbs an amount of heat $Q$ equal to that given off by $A$, and undergoes a change in volume of $\Delta V$ where now $V_{final}\lt V_{initial}$. This all occurs isothermally as system $A'$ is designated a thermal reservoir ($T'$=constant).

Since of interest is the change in entropy of $A'$, or $\Delta S'$, I will treat A' as the "system" and A as the "surroundings" (system's environment).

The initial internal energy of system A' is designated $E'$. Then, since heat $Q$ is transferred from the surroundings to system $A'$ and work $p\Delta V$ is done on system $A'$ then, from the first law, the change internal energy of system $A'$ following the process becomes

$$\Delta E'=E'_{final}-E'_{initial}=Q-p'\Delta V$$

where $Q$ is now positive for system $A'$ because it is added to $A'$, and $\Delta V$ is negative because the final volume of $A'$ is less than the initial.

*So it appears where you went wrong was in not including in the first term to the right side of your equation the energy added to $A'$ in the form of $p'\Delta V$ work done on $A'$.*

Insofar as the $pV$ work done on the reservoir A' is concerned, we can infer the work is reversible because  $A'$ and $A$ are kept in thermal and mechanical equilibrium with one another throughout the process, as stipulated in (2) above. That makes the process reversible and no entropy being generated.

Hope this helps.